# Can you create a web page table structure given below:

Tags: html, html-table, web-developer-toolbar

[Click here to view structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tnBs.png)

Each table cell is identified with a letter and all dimensions are in pixels.
The letters and dimensions shown in the table must NOT appear on your
final web page.
The external table border must have a width of 4 pixels and all internal
grid lines on the table must have a width of 2 pixels. Table borders and
grid lines must be visible.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title> Nested Table </title>
</head>

<body>

    <table border="4px" align="center" width=100%>

        <tr>
            <td height="300px" width="400px"> A 400 X 300 </td>
            <td height="300px" width="400px"> B 400 X 300 </td>
            <td height="300px" width="400px"> C 400 X 300 </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan=3 height="250px" width="1200px"> D 1200 X 250 </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan=3 height="150px" width="1200px"> E 1200 X 150 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <table border="4" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td height="300px" width="50%"> F 600 X 300 </td>
                    <td height="300px" width="600px"> G 600 X 300 </td>
                </tr>
        </tr>
        </table>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, this might sound a bit arrogant.  But what kind of site do you think this is?  I think you might be looking for freelancer.com or fiverr.com

Comment: No no that's completely fine. This que is asked by our faculty which I couldn't solve  as I'm a beginner. I'm trying since morning so I thought let's see if somebody can help me.

Comment: What have you tried?  If you are struggling with your brief, I think you should ask your faculty leaders for help instead.  SO is for devs helping each other out, not for doing your work for you.

Comment: If you are really struggling, post what you have tried and we will point you in the right direction.  Nobody is going to do the work for you.

Comment: but it's just a simple structure any pro can solve within hour minutes maybe. What wrong with it.

Comment: If other devs keep doing your work for you, how are you going to learn?  As I said, post what you have done and we will point you in the right direction.

Comment: please check the code and let me know where should I correct myself. Thank You.

Comment: jae.phoenix it would be my pleasure if you see my code and let me know the correction or a complete solution. Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```css
tr:first-child td{
height:100px;
width:100px;
}
tr:nth-child(2) td{
height:60px;
}
tr:nth-child(3) td{
height:40px;
}
tr:nth-child(4) td{
height:100px;
width:50%;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
<tr>
 <td>
 </td>
 <td>
 </td>
 <td>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan = "3">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan = "3">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan = "2">
 </td>
 <td>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I appreciate your efforts.Thank You but if u see the third row it half splited in original.

Comment: that you can set each td style as width and height.

Comment: I also facing this issue when I changed third row my first row get modified. Please see the structure and try again.Thank You.

Comment: use my code it give different css for different row.

Comment: I did for third row u can see given different height.

Comment: If this help you don’t forget to upvote and accept.

Comment: I'm trying what u said but as i'm a new comer it is taking me a time to understand small thing.

Comment: I have less than 15 reputations so vote is not casting.